# Printing images using thermal printer

Tags: thermal-printer

Thermal printer EPSON m-t532ap prints everything line by line like a dot matrix printer but if i send RAW data, text is printed at once as it should at about 10cm/s but printing image as RAW data is still slow(line by line).Is there any way to speed up printing image?

Sample of the prints:

http://postimg.org/image/ek7b3xnuz/

Comment: I faced similar problem but unfortunately no solution